# Simultaneous data access from different threads

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, winforms, entity-framework

Hi I am developing a WinForms app which is using LocalDb with EF for data access.
So far the db access in my WinForms app was performed only once at a time, just by calling:

```
using (var context = new EfDbContext())
{
     // do something on context entities
}
```

when needed.

Now I am facing a new requirement - I need to create an extra background service which will be used to periodically get the data from files located on some FTP servers, and then - update / insert the new data within this SQL LocalDb.

What I would like to achieve is to grant simultaneous access to the SQL LocalDb data for both WinForms app and this new background app (service), so that it would be possible for the user to view data from Db (in WinForm app), while an update of the data  is performed in the background (by the service).

I would like to ommit the resources blocking for each other.

Can that be done (and how to do that)?
Thanks!

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that the data sets which will be read from ftp files and then inserted into database may be quite large ~20-50k of records, each record consist of decimal field, DateTimeOffset field, and few Int32 fields.

Comment: anything tried yet ? For example just tried if it already works ?

Comment: SQL Server is inherently a multi-user RDBMS. That includes LocalDB. In fact, you'll be hard pressed to find things that handle concurrency better than SQL Server.

Comment: @FelixD. I did not try anything yet, I was reading about it and just need to know if it could be achieved or I need to switch to SqlServer and pay for it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I know, but you are talking about paid versions of SqlServer - I need it to be free, that's why I need to do it on LocalDb.

Comment: Nope. *All* versions of SQL Server work fine with concurrency. LocalDB uses the exact same engine that SQL Server Enterprise uses -- just with limits on what system resources it can utilize. You may be confused with small footprint database systems like SQLite. By default, LocalDB is configured in a way that makes it difficult to access from a remote machine, but that's an entirely different issue. You probably want Express for that (still free, still concurrent).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ok, so I should use some kind of isolation levels on the database to achieve the concurrency? Like snapshot?

Comment: You can, but you are not required to. Snapshot isolation achieves concurrency without locking, but it doesn't make conflicts go away -- it just turns them into failures that you must retry. As a first approach, the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level works fine for most applications.

Comment: It is not easy work for beginner if the update is complex i.e. the data integrity in the view is important. If you have only 1 or 2 tables with data, then there is no problem with simultaneous access. Post example of inserted and displayed data.

Comment: @i486 Well, I have quite a lot of data in this database, and when it comes to the amount of data which could be inserted / updated in db by the service -> thousands of records, like ~20-50k per single file read from ftp.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks. I have few more questions to be specific.
1. Could I use same DAL for db access for both WinForm app and the background service? I mean - can I use the EfDbContext exactly the same way for both apps simultaneously?
2. When READ COMMITTED isolation is used, wouldn't the db data insertion process block the read operations?
How this lock works - whole modified table is locked or only rows affected at the time?

Comment: SO comments are not for extended support sessions. If you have questions, ask them as questions (after looking for existing ones plus answers, of course). And unless you're defusing a bomb or you're launching a rover to Mars, trying things out for yourself rather than believing strangers on the Internet *a priori* is often the superior option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use it and don't worry for now about concurrency. SQL Server widely used in highly concurrent applications like ASP.NET Web Apps and your example isn't so special. Blocking can be a problem when using transactions with write operations. But there are many [Transaction isolation levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173763.aspx) to solve this problem and it's irrelevant for now for your task I think